# How to proxy editingDidEnd from UITableViewCell to UITableViewController?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4

I have a custom UITableViewCell:

```
@interface EditingTableViewCell : UITableViewCell <UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UITextField *editableText;
    UILabel *textLabel;
}
```

And I did receive `editingDidEnd` message from UITextField `editableText`. Now how can I pass it's message to UITableViewController which creates this cell?
Is creating ivar like this `id delegate;` within cell and set it to the tableViewController instance an only way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found a way to do a good job...

- Create `@protocol` for this cell

```
    // EditingCellDelegate.h
    @protocol EditingCellDelegate 
     @optional
        - (void)textLabelEditDidEnd:(UITextField *)textField;

    @end
```

- Add ivar into `EditingTableViewCell` class

```
    // EditingTableViewCell.h
    ...
    @property (nonatomic, assign) id <EditingCellDelegate> delegate;
```

So this way i can pass message to the UITableViewController that conforms that cell's protocol. Of course you have to check that class `conformsToProtocol` and `respondsToSelector`. Now I can call it. Something like this:

```
//EditingTableViewCell.m
- (IBAction)editDone:(id)sender {
    if([[self delegate] respondsToSelector:@selector(textLabelEditDidEnd:)]) {
        [[self delegate] textLabelEditDidEnd:(UITextField *)sender];
    }
}
```